# Get DisplayName Attribute without using LabelFor Helper in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

What is the best way to retrieve the display name attribute for an item in your model? I see a lot of people using the LabelFor helper for everything, but a label isn't appropriate if I just want to list the data out. Is there an easy way just get the Name Attribute if I just want to print it out in, say a paragraph?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
<p>
    <%= Html.Encode(
        ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<YourViewModel, string>(
            x => x.SomeProperty, ViewData).DisplayName
    ) %>
<p>
```

Obviously in order to avoid the spaghetti code it is always a good idea to write a helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString GetDisplayName<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
    )
    {
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TProperty>(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        string value = metaData.DisplayName ?? (metaData.PropertyName ?? ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(value);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
<p>
    <%: Html.GetDisplayName(x => x.SomeProperty) %>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, That's exactly what I'm after plus more!

Comment: Note that you need the following `using`s for this: using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

Comment: What are the performance implications of doing this? I like the idea of using this in all the views, but it sounds way more complex than just having the text in the .cshtml

Comment: Does anyone know whether this was added in MVC3 or MVC4 beta?

Comment: It's called DisplayNameFor in MVC 4.

Comment: Yeah MVC 4+ should use this extension method instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17471459/383761

Answer (score 76):

You should try new existing function :

```
<% Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.YourProperty) %>
```

Comment: Razor: @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SomeProperty)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should use a string as a result type because otherwise you skip the encoding mechanism. Another point is that you need the DisplayName in some cases as a string (i.e. populate the columns in a WebGrid class).