# Get the DisplayName of a property on an arbitrary type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble figuring out a clean way to do this. I have a `ViewModel` class that contains a collection of rows for a table. I would like to be able to do an `@Html.DisplayNameFor()` on the type in the `strongly-typed` collection without referring to the first item in the collection or creating a new instance of the type. So to clarify here's an example:

```
public class TableViewModel
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
  public int ColumnA { get; set; }
  public int ColumnB { get; set; }
}

//In the Razor view
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(???)</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way to do this without doing `@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Rows.First().ColumnA)`?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885796/get-displayname-attribute-without-using-labelfor-helper-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: You could add `public Row Row { get; set; }` to your view model.

Comment: @LeviBotelho - I saw that question in my research, but it doesn't exactly fit the bill, since it doesn't deal with a collection.

Comment: @Forty-Two - I guess what I'm envisioning is a helper method solution. I'm not crazy about adding an extra property to my VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties` collection and call the `GetDisplayName` method to generate the header cell content. We do this generically in our code to render an arbitrary model as a table.

Edit:
To expand on this, I use a basic model that represents a table and only a table. I have 3 classes defined. I have a `TableRowCell' class, a`TableRow' class (which is essentially a collection of `TableRowCell` objects) and a `Table` class.

```
public class Table
{
    public Table(String name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.ContentRows = new List<TableRow>();
        this.HeaderRow = new TableRow();
        this.FooterRow = new TableRow();
    } 

    public IList<TableRow> ContentRows
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public TableRow FooterRow
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public TableRow HeaderRow
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public String Name
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

When I have a view model that contains a collection of objects that I want to display in a table I call first an `HtmlHelper` extension that converts that collection into a `Table` object. Inside that method I iterate over a call to `ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, typeof(TModel)).Properties..Where(item => item.ShowForDisplay)` to get a collection of metadata objects used to generate the header cells. I then iterate over the collection of items and call `ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => item, typeof(TModel)).Properties..Where(item => item.ShowForDisplay)` to get a collection of metadata objects used to generate the content cells.

Technically, my `HtmlHelper` extension method actually returns a `TableBuilder` object which will has a method called `Render` on it which generates the html. That setup has served me well so far.

Comment: How would you do this for the type generic type in an IEnumerable? I.E for IEnumerable<Row>, how do I get the metadata for Row?

Comment: I elaborated in my answer a bit  in an attempt to address your question.

Comment: Excellent, the `ModelMetadataProvers.Current.GetMetadataForType` method was just what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TableViewModel
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Row> Rows { get; set; }
  public Row ForNames = null;
}


@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.ForName.ColumnA)
```