# Another way to do @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.myField), to get the Field Title without surrounding elements?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET 4.5, Razor.

Normally I would use, to get a standard title for my DB columns:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.myField)
```

Which would produce:

```
<label for="myField">MyField Title</label>
```

However I need to produce just "MyField Title" which will exist in some "th" elements such as:

```
<th>MyField Title</th>
```

So I need some code like:

```
<th>@{get Field Title}</th>
```

I am probably missing an obviously trick here.....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For MVC4, you can use the DisplayNameFor helper

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.MyField)
```

For MVC3, this helper doesn't exist, so you can use something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3885876/74022) instead to read directly from the `[DisplayName]` attribute (which you will have to add to your property).

Comment: Thanks this was incredibly useful. I used Darin's extension code, and it worked a treat. Another reason to get on and upgrade to MVC4 or 5.... Thanks again. One learns something every day.