# ASP.NET MVC - Show raw DisplayName of an item of the Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

e.g. i have a class

```
public class Car
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Brand { get; set; }
     public string Color { get; set; }
 }
```

and i have a view with a model as a list

```
@model IEnumerable<Car>
```

Now i want to display the raw displayName of a property of a listItem (model).

Example code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Car>

//(..)

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>"[@Html.DisplayName(Model.First().Name))]"</th>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Color</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

How can I do it?

**UPDATE**

I found the solution in creating a new helper class:
[click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885796/get-displayname-attribute-without-using-labelfor-helper-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @PeterB with "Model.First()" I can access the property values. But i actually don't want to display the values but the displayname of a property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get \[DisplayName\] attribute of a property in strongly-typed way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474460/get-displayname-attribute-of-a-property-in-strongly-typed-way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get

```
<th>DisplayName</th>
```

by using

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Name)
```

The solution you've used is quite old and doesn't use the built in helper.

Answer (score 0):

Use LabelFor

```
<th>@Html.LabelFor(p => p.First().Name)<th>
```

Don't forget the display Attribute on Car Class

```
[DisplayName("Car Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: with LabelFor I'll get the displayname i want in a "label", but i want to have the raw value: `<th>Name</th>` and not `<th><label>Name</label></th>`

Comment: Ok, you can get it by reflection                                                                      
using System.Reflection;                                                                              
 var name = ((DisplayAttribute)(typeof(Car).GetProperty("Name").GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute)))).Name;